# Bootstrap vue: form-group label styling

Tags: css, bootstrap-vue

I am trying t style label for form-group in bootstrap vue, but it's not working. I have try everything but no luck. I could really need some help how to do this.

```css
.add-style label {

color: red;

}
```

```html
<b-container>

<b-form-group class="add-style" label="Product Name">
          <b-form-input type="text" id="pName" required
                        placeholder="Enter product name"/>
        </b-form-group>

</b-container>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in this way:

```
<b-container>

<b-form-group class="add-style">
          <label style="color: red;" for="pName">Product Name:</label>
          <b-form-input type="text" id="pName" required
                        placeholder="Enter product name"/>
        </b-form-group>

</b-container>
```

Or, if you don't want to use inline css then you can do it in this way:

Css:

```
label {
    color: red;
}
```

Html:

```
<b-container>

    <b-form-group class="add-style">
              <label for="pName">Product Name:</label>
              <b-form-input type="text" id="pName" required
                            placeholder="Enter product name"/>
            </b-form-group>

    </b-container>
```

Comment: how to make red color only on text * so the symbol color is red . symbol only. thats mean mandatory.

Answer (score 3):

The thing is if you are using css you must use either selector (class or id) or the tag elements not both. You are using both i.e. **.add-style label**. Here **.add-style** is a class and label is a tag element.

Also there has to be some text inside your  markup to see the effect. I have used simple text. You can replace with your own vue text(or whatever you call in your language for e.g. {page.Title}) as per your requirement:

```css
.add-style{

color: red;

}
```

```html
<b-container>

<b-form-group class="add-style" label="Product Name">
          <b-form-input type="text" id="pName" required
                        placeholder="Enter product name"/>
                  test
        </b-form-group>

</b-container>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried the `label-class` [prop](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-group#comp-ref-b-form-group-props)?